# An empty grid column in HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css, grid-system

In `row1` I have 4 columns(filled) and in the `row2` I want my 2nd column to be empty and take space,
but 3rd column moves left and occupies the 2nd column. I don't want to use tables and `&nbsp`.

```css
.col {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 4%;
  float: left;
}

.col:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.col3 {
  width: 21.98%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row1">
  <div class="col col3">Lorem</div>
  <div class="col col3">Lorem</div>
  <div class="col col3">Lorem</div>
  <div class="col col3">Lorem</div>
</div>
<div class="row2">
  <div class="col col3">Lorem</div>
  <div class="col col3"></div>
  <div class="col col3">Lorem</div>
  <div class="col col3">Lorem</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set an offset, but if you still want that empty col in you DOM, then you  can do a simple hack by inserting a empty space `&nbsp;`.

You can use bootstrap's class `col-md-offset-3` assigned to the third column if you don't want to use the empty space hack.

```css
.col {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 4%;
  float: left;
}

.col:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.col3 {
  width: 21.98%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row1">
  <div class="col col3">Lorem</div>
  <div class="col col3">Lorem</div>
  <div class="col col3">Lorem</div>
  <div class="col col3">Lorem</div>
</div>
<div class="row2">
  <div class="col col3">Lorem</div>
  <div class="col col3">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="col col3">Lorem</div>
  <div class="col col3">Lorem</div>
</div>
```

Here is another example by using `.col-md-offset-3`  class custom defined.

```css
.col {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 4%;
  float: left;
}

.col:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.col3 {
  width: 21.98%;
}

.col-md-offset-3 {
  margin-left: 25.98%; /* combined margin = default margin (4%) + col width (21.98%) */
}
```

```html
<div class="row1">
  <div class="col col3">Lorem</div>
  <div class="col col3">Lorem</div>
  <div class="col col3">Lorem</div>
  <div class="col col3">Lorem</div>
</div>
<div class="row2">
  <div class="col col3">Lorem</div>
  <div class="col col3"></div>
  <div class="col col3 col-md-offset-3">Lorem</div>
  <div class="col col3">Lorem</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess I answer it first :)

Comment: Yes, first at the photo finish :)

Comment: &nbsp takes some empty text in the empty space. Use CTRL+A in your output page it will be in blue highlighted.

Comment: bootstrap doesn't use gutter spaces. Here i'm using 4% of gutter space in between each column

Answer (score 0):

This happens as there is no content to occupy space, so you can add a `min-height` value with smallest unit you want to add (pixel being the smallest unit on screen), like I have added a `min-height:1px`. It keeps my layout flow proper.

```css
.col {
  margin-right: 4%;
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
  /* give a small space - practiced by Bootstrap framework as well */
}

.col:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.col3 {
  width: 21.98%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row1">
  <div class="col col3">Lorem</div>
  <div class="col col3">Lorem</div>
  <div class="col col3">Lorem</div>
  <div class="col col3">Lorem</div>
</div>
<div class="row2">
  <div class="col col3">Lorem</div>
  <div class="col col3"></div>
  <div class="col col3">Lorem</div>
  <div class="col col3">Lorem</div>
</div>
```

Comment: min-height takes some empty text in the empty space. Use CTRL+A in your output page it will be in blue highlighted.

Comment: it is a widely used practice, you can check the  And if you don't want then go for `&nbsp;` approach. But then you'll have to write it everytime in similar scenario you use your grid system.
And it does not appear in browser when pressed `CTRL+A`.